# Use Kubernetes with QUIC and HTTP/3

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress, quic, http3

Is there a way to configure Kubernetes to work with HTTP/3 and QUIC?

[QUIC protocol](https://quicwg.org/) is a quite new transport protocol, explained in the [RFC9000](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9000.html), that many research highlight to mix the advantages of TCP and UDP protocols.

The only thing I found is that NGINX is developing a branch [nginx-quic](https://quic.nginx.org/) to add the support for QUIC but is still on in beta version and I don't know how to try inside Kubernetes.

I cannot find a solution to configure Services and Ingress, within a Kubernetes deployment, with QUIC.

Answer (score 1):

This was the last update from the Roadmap for QUIC and HTTP/3 Support in NGINX [article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/our-roadmap-quic-http-3-support-nginx/#comment-5884347500) from about three months ago:

> The latest update for our QUIC+HTTP/3 implementation is the release of [binary packages](https://www.nginx.com/blog/binary-packages-for-preview-nginx-quic-http3-implementation/). The plan is to merge the QUIC+HTTP/3 into the NGINX Open Source mainline branch in the next few months, but I don't have an exact date. To be sure you know as soon as the merge happens, you can subscribe to this [link](https://mailman.nginx.org/mailman/listinfo/nginx-announce)